# Sound comes from just the bass speakers instead of all 4 built in speakers

Tags: 11.10, sound

So I feel like I've tried everything from changing settings in alsamixer and pulse audio volume controller, to editing alsa.conf files, to purging and reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio, to outright formatting and reinstalling.

This happens when I installed Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10, as well as Mint 11 and 12.

This is my lspci -v:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: c0000000-d30fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at d3400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at e0e0 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d7409000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei

00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d7407000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at d7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
    Memory behind bridge: d6000000-d73fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d7700000-00000000d78fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000b000-0000bfff
    Memory behind bridge: d4c00000-d5ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d7500000-00000000d76fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000a000-0000afff
    Memory behind bridge: d3800000-d4bfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d3100000-00000000d32fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at d7406000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=128
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at e0d0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e0c0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e090 [size=16]
    I/O ports at e080 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at d7405000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at e070 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e060 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e040 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e030 [size=16]
    I/O ports at e020 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at d7404000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel ips
    Kernel modules: intel_ips

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 425M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at d2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at d000 [disabled] [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at d3000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidiafb

02:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci-hcd

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 1075
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    I/O ports at b000 [size=256]
    Memory at d4c04000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d4c00000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at d3800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlagn
    Kernel modules: iwlagn

ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 8086
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
```

And my aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

If anyone knows a fix or can help walk me along to find the problem, please please respond!

Comment: Also, upon careful listening, it seems to be actually coming from the bass speakers just under the keyboard of the laptop..the problem is it's not coming out of the main speakers which are just above the keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Try 
`aplay -D plughw:0,1 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`

Dose this give an error?

This is assuming you are plugging the speakers into the headphone port.

Google turned out this

[Fix Headphone sound problem](http://digitizor.com/2009/10/22/fix-headphone-sound-problem-hp-laptop-linux/)

good sound resources for ubuntu

[Old sound troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting)

I have used this one a lot in the past to solve sound issues.

[Newer sound troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting)

This one doesn't seem to have as much information. But it is the official sound troubleshooting for ubuntu.

Comment: Trying that command gave me:
`Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono`

Comment: Also, the speakers I'm referring to are the built in speakers of the laptop, not ones plugged in or anything.

Comment: Well it didn't give you and error so that good. That means it found it but if it didn't play sound it could be an issue with alsamixer or alsa.conf.

Comment: Are you sure everything is not muted in alsamixer you have two different devices (analog and digital). Press F2 in alsamixer to cycle though the driver to make sure they are not muted. Also try and replace 0,1 with 1,1 in the above command.